# Кнопка исчезает при повороте

Tags: android

Примерная верстка.

```
<ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mainScroller">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mainLayout">
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/horLineHeight"
        android:background="@color/vColor"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
    </View>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/textMargin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/textMargin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/textMargin"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:id="@+id/footerRelative">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        style="@style/btnStyle"
        android:gravity="center"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

В портретном режиме все нормально, а когда поворачивааешь, скролл нормально работает, а кнопки нету, вообще! Что не так?

Comment: Добавьте родительский layout для вышенаписанного кода

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот что мне помогло, может и кому поможет...

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/textMargin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/textMargin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/textMargin"
android:id="@+id/footerRelative">
<ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/mainScroller">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout">
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/horLineHeight"
    android:background="@color/vColor"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_gravity="center">
</View>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    style="@style/btnStyle"
    android:gravity="center"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```